# Wordpress 3.5 Media Uploader - Only allow 1 upload and certain file types

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, uploads, media

I am trying to include the new WP Media Uploader in a Custom Meta Box.

I found [this tutorial](http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/).

However, I am looking for a way to limit the uploader to only accept certain types of files like 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/pdf', etc. and to return the linked document url to a text field i have in the metabox

Any ideas, links or just basically anything to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97025/2487

Answer (score 1):

The file types that you have specified 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/pdf' are already supported by media uploader.

To see the default supported mime file types, call [wp_get_mime_types()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_mime_types) function.

Use [upload_mimes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes) filter as shown in following code  to make media uploader to accept files types other than the default.

Add following code in your themes functions.php file

```
// Add the filter
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {

// Add file extension 'extension' with mime type 'mime/type'
$existing_mimes['prc'] = 'application/x-mobipocket'; 

// and return the new full result
return $existing_mimes; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i limit the mime types to only the selected mime types for that specific instance of the media upload? I don't want to limit the standard WP Editor upload to those same mime types...

Answer (score 0):

Like Vinod Dalvi said, you could use the filter upload_mimes to achieve what you need.
You can deregister existing mimes types using

```
unset($mime_types['pdf']);
```

and adding new type by adding then to the array :

```
$mime_types['avi'] = 'video/avi';
```

for instance

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['avi'] = 'video/avi'; //Adding avi extension
    unset($mime_types['pdf']); //Removing the pdf extension
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

This is taken from [here](http://msyk.es/blog/adding-removing-allowed-filetypes-wordpress-media-library/)

You say :

> how do i limit the mime types to only the selected mime types for that
> specific instance of the media upload? I don't want to limit the
> standard WP Editor upload to those same mime types

Do you mean limiting mime type only for one type of uploader ? I can't see the logic involved, since if there are other "instances" of media uploader, "forbidden" media types could be uploaded anyway.